# Message without dot notation?

Tags: objective-c

Quick question, could anyone help me out with regards to writing this without dot notation? (i.e. [self setView? ...)

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```

many thanks, gary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[[self view] setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[[self view] setTransform: CGAffineTransformIdentity];
```